# How do you plot a horizontal line across the chart at the highest and lowest price of the last 2 candles with pine script?

Tags: pine-script

How can you plot two horizontal lines. 1 line at the highest price of the most recent 2 candles and 1 line at the lowest price of the most recent 2 candles, using pine script?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("Help", overlay=true)

var ln_max = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.left, color=color.orange)
var ln_min = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.left, color=color.blue)

H2=max(high[1], high[0])
L2=min(low[1], low[0])

if bar_index > 1
    line.set_xy1(ln_max, bar_index - 1, H2)
    line.set_xy2(ln_max, bar_index, H2)
    line.set_xy1(ln_min, bar_index - 1, L2)
    line.set_xy2(ln_min, bar_index, L2)
```

[image]